# Spectral sequence for equivariant group extension

Tags: group-cohomology

Suppose that $A,B$ and $C$ are groups and that a fourth group $G$ acts on all three by automorphisms.  If there is a short exact sequence
$$ (*)\ \ \ \ \ \ 1\rightarrow A\rightarrow B\rightarrow C\rightarrow 1 $$
compatible with the $G$-actions, is the (co)homological Hochschild-Serre spectral sequence for (*) (with $\mathbb{Q}$-coefficients, say) a spectral sequence of $G$-modules? I am sure this must be known, but I have not been able to find a reference and haven't quite been able to work it out myself.

Comment: I assume this is a particular case of a Grothendieck spectral sequence. Identify the two functors $F$ and $G$ and compute (or at least identify is what I mean) their derived functors $R^pF$, $R^qG$ and $R^r(G \circ F)$. If all three constructions map $G$-modules to $G$-modules, you have your answer. Did you try doing that?